# Why 'shuffle' isnt defined?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I programmed a code today, but I couldn't use it.

Please see the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="random,variable name">
        <title>Random Variable Name Maker</title>
    </head>

    <body background="WT.png">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <input id="string" value="Click the following button!"><br>
        <button onClick="shuffle()">Shuffle!</button>
        <p>Click <b>Ctrl</b> + <b>A</b> to Select All<br>Click <b>Ctrl</b> + <b>C</b> to Copy</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var charlist[46] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

function shuffle() {
    var name = document.getElementById("string").value;
    var string;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 46) + 1);
        var char = charlist[rand];
        string += char;
    }
    name = string;
}
```

I expect the output is a string, but there is an error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: shuffle is not defined
    
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some error with your code:

```
var charlist[46] => var charlist = "";

onClick => onclick

for (int i = 0 => for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
var string => var string = "";

value="Click the following button!" => placeholder="Click the following button!"
```

May be need reassign to original `document.getElementById("string").value = name;`

Also check that put `script` tag before `</body>` tag.

```js
var charlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

function shuffle() {
    var name = document.getElementById("string").value;
    var string = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 46) + 1);
        var char = charlist[rand];
        string += char;
    }
    name = string;
    
    document.getElementById("string").value = name;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="random,variable name">
        <title>Random Variable Name Maker</title>
    </head>

    <body background="WT.png">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <input id="string" placeholder="Click the following button!"><br>
        <button onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle!</button>
        <p>Click <b>Ctrl</b> + <b>A</b> to Select All<br>Click <b>Ctrl</b> + <b>C</b> to Copy</p>
    </body>
</html>
```